# Removing points from the discrete spectrum of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

I'm currently following the chapter 6 of Gerald Teschl's book "Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics" and got stuck in something that seems irrelevant but is killing me anyway.

As a example of how inestable is the discrete spectrum, it is stated in the book that: Given an self-adjoint operator $A$ and $\lambda_0\in \sigma_{dis}(A)$, we can easily remove this eigenvalue with a finite rank perturbation of arbitrarily small norm. In fact, consider 
$$A+\varepsilon P_{\{\lambda_0\}}(A).$$

While it is easy to see that such perturbation is of finite rank and its norm is arbitrarily small, understanding why $\lambda_0$ can not be an eigenvalue anymore is not clear at all.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 4):

Let $V$ be the eigenspace of $A$ for eigenvalue $\lambda_0$.
If $v \in V$, then $(A + \epsilon P_{\lambda_0}(A)) v = (\lambda_0 + \epsilon) v$.  An eigenvector $w$ of $A + \epsilon P_{\lambda_0}(A)$ for any eigenvalue other than $\lambda_0 + \epsilon$ must be orthogonal to $V$, so $(A + \epsilon P_{\lambda_0}(A)) w = A w$, and thus $w$ would be an eigenvector of $A$ for some eigenvalue other than $\lambda_0$.

Comment: I hope these are not goint to be dumb questions: First, is it obvious that $\varepsilon P_{\{\lambda_0\}}(A)v=\varepsilon v$? Second, that $w$ is orthogonal to $V$ imply $\varepsilon P_{\{\lambda_0\}}(A)w=0$? And finally. How did you conclude that the eigenvalue associated to $w$ can not be $\lambda_0$?

Comment: 1) Yes: $P_{\{\lambda_0\}}$ is the orthogonal projection on $V$.  2) It's an orthogonal projection, so it maps anything orthogonal to $V$ to $0$.  3)  Because $w$ is orthogonal to $V$.

Comment: It's difficult to learn without a teacher because it's easy to get gaps and then get stuck in dumb things. Anyway, I've been thinking about your answer and it finally makes sense, but I have a final question. It seems that this is something that I should have learned in the Spectral Theorem Chapter but I still don't get it: Do you know where could I read a detailed proof of the fact that $P_{\{\lambda\}}$ is in deed the orthogonal projection on the eigenspace associated to $\lambda$?